# Steps to Debug Npm Header Contains Invalid Characters Error

Tags: node.js, npm, http-headers, npm-install

I am new to npm and node.  Currently I am trying to use `npm install` to get the dependencies for my project which requires a call to my companies local npm registry to link a project.  During install I get this error:

```
npm verb stack TypeError: The header content contains invalid characters
npm verb stack     at ClientRequest.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:348:11)
npm verb stack     at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:85:14)
npm verb stack     at Object.exports.request (http.js:31:10)
npm verb stack     at Object.exports.request (https.js:199:15)
npm verb stack     at Request.start (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:740:32)
npm verb stack     at Request.end (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:1398:10)
npm verb stack     at end (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:567:14)
npm verb stack     at Immediate.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:581:7)
npm verb stack     at runCallback (timers.js:566:20)
npm verb stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:546:5)
npm verb cwd /Users/amohnacs/Developer/git/example-data-sync
npm ERR! Darwin 16.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-verbose"
npm ERR! node v6.3.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9

npm ERR! The header content contains invalid characters
```

Doing a little digging it seems that is a fairly generic error. It can occur from just an invalid header in a request when testing an http request or an empty request.  It can also occur from the wrong language set for the OS or server. There was even at one point people saying an old karma dependency resulting in invalid characters in test requests.

My question is how do I go about debugging this problem as I am unsure how to print the headers before the request fails and I am unable to include code in my project that pulls down the headers during the request because the headers need to succeed before my application can run.

Thanks in advance.